# UNITY 2D - Can't change Child's position

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, 2d

I have created a project and put a character in it, a Ninja. I drew every part of his body and put them together into one organized gameObject. It is organized as this.
[Ninja Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDnV.png)

NOTE : The `Left_Arm` GameObject has a parent so it can be rotated by the shoulder like a real arm

Now here comes the problem. I've searched and searched for hours and haven't found a solution to something that is surely so simple and dumb. In a script, I try to move the `Left_Arm` parent for a little animation. Here's the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NinjaShooting : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("GameObjects")]
    public Transform leftArm;
    public Transform rightArm;

    [Header("Other")]
    public bool shooting = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

            Debug.Log(leftArm.localPosition);
            leftArm.localPosition = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
            Debug.Log(leftArm.localPosition);
            shooting = false;

    }  
}
```

The public variables are all assigned and everything, there are no errors in the console, but the line `leftArm.localPosition = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);` doesn't seem to do a thing to my character.

Here's is the Console after running it : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAUEG.png)

The console seems alright. The start position is (-0.3, 0.2, 0) and after `leftArm.localPosition = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);` the position is debugged as (100, 100, 100) as it should be. But the position changes in the inspector, nor in the game window...

Additionnally, the starter position is debugged every frame, but it shouldn't. So I assume that my position isn't taken into account or something.

I've done this so many times, and always has worked.

I even tried with a new project and recreated it, and there, mysteriously, it worked. So there is someting wrong with my organization or something. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thank you in advance

PS : Here is an image of the script in the editor, just in case there something wrong with that : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HajQ.png)

PS : The script is a it weird because I simplified it :). But this doesn't work too

Comment: Are there any animations / Animators active anywhere in the GameObject? Have you tried stepping through this frame by frame? (Pause and use the skip frame button, both are next to the "Play in editor" button).

Comment: Try changing the field types "Transform" to "GameObject" and drag the arms into them.

Comment: @Kwinten yes, there are animations and an animator, but just want to make the arm move. Maybe animation is the wrong word to use in my question. And yes I have tried going it frame by frame. t I can't see any problems....

Comment: @Immorality I tried that it didn't work neither....

Comment: I'm talking specifically about the Unity `Animator` or `Animation` components. In many cases, animations will "lock" the properties they are targeting, even if they are not animating anything. Try disabling all such components, with only your "custom" script to animate the arm active.

Comment: @Kwinten that's it Thank you so MUCH. But how to I then have both ? Is it posible ? Post it as an answer and I'll put is at correct Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by an `Animator` controller "locking" properties that are not actually part of its `Motion`. In this case, it is "locking" the `Transform`'s position. Unity does not report any warnings or errors when you try to modify those properties, even if they are being controlled by an animation.

The typical offender is the `Write Defaults` property being set to true for your `Animation States` in your animation controller. Have a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html) at the documentation for what `Write Defaults` does, and it will make more sense to you. I suggest changing it to false for all animation states that do not need it.

Comment: Your right! When I disable the Animator it works, but even if I have every state Write Defaults to false. It doesn't work. What's the problem ? Sorry for asking so many questions...

Comment: Try disabling and enabling the animations one by one to find the offending `Animator`. When you find what is causing the issue, upload a screenshot so we can have a look. It would also be good to know which objects in the hierarchy you are animating. In general, it is bad practice to animate a root object (since it can cause issues like this).

Comment: Changing Write Defauts didn't do anything. But I changed Update() to LateUpadte() and that foxed it. Thank you again! :)